# Spring Cloud Stream messages based on polymorphic class structure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitBinder for pub/sub message processing.

Events emitted from services are sent via the broker. The event class structure is polymorphic, i.e. there is

```
abstract class OrderEvent {
 abstract String type();
}

class OrderCreatedEvent extends OrderEvent {
  @Override
  String type() {
   return "ORDER_CREATED";
  }
  ...
}

abstract class OrderLineEvent extends OrderEvent {
  ...
}

class OrderLineCreatedEvent extends OrderLineEvent {
  ...
}
```

I am publishing events via StreamBridge,

```
 @Override
  public void publish(List<OrderEvent> events) {
    events.forEach(e -> {
      streamBridge.send("order-out-0", e);
    });
  }
```

and consuming via reactive consumer

```
  @Bean
  public Consumer<OrderEvent> order() {
    return orderEvent -> {
      System.out.println("got order event" + orderEvent);
    };
  }
```

But how to properly deserialize polymorphic types? content-type is set to application/json.
The code above does not work, it throws IllegalArgumentException, can not cast to OrderEvent.
If I restrict the code to publish OrderCreatedEvent (or any other leaf class) only, and adjust the consumer to OrderCreatedEvent the events are received successfully.

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Andreas

Comment: You have to annotate the class with `@JsonSchemaInject` and each attribute with `@JsonProperty`. Then I think you cannot use `abstract class`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll have a look at JsonSchemaInject. What are possible alternatives to my approach. One exchange including producer and consumer per leaf class (event)? But this requires a lot of boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of disadvantages of using an Event class hierarchy. This is one. The other is that you share event types across distributed components which requires upgrading all dependent components whenever you add a new event type. I prefer using a single type with an event type field as a string.